# GitHub - only allow pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a public github repo and want to disallow other users to merge into the master branch. They should only be able to create other branches and create pull request. I'm the only one who accept and merge pull requests.

Is this possible with GitHub and if yes, how can I set this up?

Kind regards

Comment: Even on a public repo, only people who've you have added to the project are allowed to commit to the project, other people would have to submit a pull request.

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

By design, all public repositories are read-only when you create them. If you're a member of [an organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), you can provide default permissions to do otherwise.

Long and short of it, GitHub does what you wish it to by design.